# Conditonal $set in mongoose with findAndUpdateOne

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to update a key only if it does not exist in the database already when i findAndUpdateOne in mongoose with `options : { upsert: true, new: true,}`.

This is my update

```
update = {
                            $addToSet: {
                                items: body.item,
                            },
                            
                            $set: {
                                "cover": {
                                    $cond: {
                                        if: { $exists: false },
                                        then: String(product.Images),

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            
                        },
```

This gives me CastError.

Answer (score 2):

`$cond` is an aggregation operator.  In order to use aggregation operators in an update, you need to use the pipeline form.

Additionally, you could use the `$ifNull` operator to accomplish the conditional in a single operation, like:

```
update = [
  {$set:{
     items: {$setUnion:["$items", body.item]},
     cover: {$ifNull:["$cover", String(product.Images)]}
  }}
]
```